# Kotlin - How to make a property delegate by map with a custom name?

Tags: properties, delegates, kotlin, delegation

I'm trying to get my head around property delegates, and I have an interesting use case. Is it possible to have something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    val properties = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    val fontSize: Any by MapDelegate(properties, "font-size")
}
```

That would allow me to store `fontSize` using the map as a delegate, but with a custom key (i.e. "font-size").

The specific use case if for storing things like CSS property tags that can be accessed through variables (`fontSize`) for use in code, but can be rendered properly when iterating through the map (`font-size: 18px;`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation on [the delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) is a good source of information on the topic. It probably is a bit longer read than the following examples:

```
fun <T, TValue> T.map(properties: MutableMap<String, TValue>, key: String): ReadOnlyProperty<T, TValue> {
    return object : ReadOnlyProperty<T, TValue> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>) = properties[key]!!
    }
}

class MyClass {
    val properties = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    val fontSize: Any by map(properties, "font-size")
}
```

You can ease up things a little bit and avoid typing the CSS property name by converting Kotlin property names to CSS attributes equivalents like so:

```
fun <T, TValue> map(properties: Map<String, TValue>, naming:(String)->String): ReadOnlyProperty<T, TValue?> {
    return object : ReadOnlyProperty<T, TValue?> {
        override fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>) = properties[naming(property.name)]
    }
}

object CamelToHyphen : (String)->String {
    override fun invoke(camelCase: String): String {
        return CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN, camelCase)
    }
}

fun <T, TValue> T.cssProperties(properties: Map<String,TValue>) = map(properties, CamelToHyphen)

class MyClass {
    val properties = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    val fontSize: Any? by cssProperties(properties)
}
```

The above sample uses Guava's [`CaseFormat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_HYPHEN).

If you'd like to have mutable property your delegate will have to implement setter method:

```
fun <T, TValue> map(properties: MutableMap<String, TValue?>, naming: (String) -> String): ReadWriteProperty<T, TValue?> {
    return object : ReadWriteProperty<T, TValue?> {
        override fun setValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>, value: TValue?) {
            properties[naming(property.name)] = value
        }

        override fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>) = properties[naming(property.name)]
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the documentation, but was having a hard time figuring out what I needed to do. This made it perfectly clear. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using the first option (without the auto-conversion) to allow supporting JavaFX style CSS: `var fontSize: Any? by map(properties, "-fx-font-size")`